# How to trigger an action in the activity an intent is referencing?

Tags: android

My app is workout themed and I have two activities, main_activity that has a listview, and another activity that prompts the user to enter information and saves that information in the listview. Think a to-do list. When I click the add_workout button the main activity to go to the 2nd one it creates an item. Then when the save button is hit (save button is on the 2nd activity) I want the information to be saved and shown on the item that was just created in the listview. How should I do this?

My code for a SAVE button:

```
                Intent i2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                String workoutName = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterName)).getText().toString();
                i2.putExtra("workoutName", workoutName);
                startActivity(i2);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Workout Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
```

My code for Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private TextView preset;
    private Button add;
    private ListView workouts;

    private ArrayList<String> workName;
    public ArrayList<Workout> workList;
    private MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        preset = findViewById(R.id.preset_title);
        add = findViewById(R.id.add_workout);
        workouts = findViewById(R.id.workouts);

        workName = FileHelper.readData(this);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, workName);
        workouts.setAdapter(adapter);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        workouts.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.add_workout:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, AddWorkout.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Intent i2 = getIntent();
                String itemEntered = i2.getStringExtra("workoutName"); 
                adapter.add(itemEntered);
                FileHelper.writeData(workName, this);
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        workName.remove(i);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending data from an Activity to a previous Activity involves three steps.

**Step 1**

In firstActivity, start the secondActivity like this:

```
final int CODE = 1; // This is your request code. It can be whatever you want just make sure to keep track of it as you'll use it in third step.
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
```

**Step 2**

In secondActivity, pass back whatever information you want like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(key, value);
setResult(RESULT_OK /*This is a result code. RESULT_CANCEL is the other */, intent);
finish();
```

**Step 3**

Lastly, in firstActivity you need to override the method [onActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) like so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case CODE: // From step 1
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK /*From step 2*/ && data != null) {
                // Get data from secondActivity, which in your case is a string
                String str = data.getStringExtra(key);
            }
        default:
            // Do w/e     
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you!! it worked. After retrieving the data, how would I update my item's textview? I have a custom listview with a custom adapter.